# Can I use a universal 22" wood saw for cutting studwork?

Tags: wood, woodworking, saw

I'm a newbie and do not have much experience with sawing, or working with wood.

I need to buy and cut into various lengths some wood for studwork (at varying thickness levels).

What kind of saw would be most appropriate for the job?

Later I will work with bigger pieces of wood. Can I just buy a 22" universal wood saw now (~7 tpi), and use it for both jobs?

Comment: If this is for finer woodworking then I would post on the new woodworking.SE.  If this is for basic home framing then I would buy a circular/table/mitre saw.

Comment: circular/table/mitre saw is a great idea. do they all do the job pretty much ok? I could consider buying one of the cheaper ones but if they are terrible then I will need to buy a manual saw. Thanks!

Comment: If it is just studs the easiest is a mitre saw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is for studwork, i.e. constructing internal wood-framed walls, doorways etc, a 22" 7tpi saw should be suitable.

You would use a finer-toothed saw if you need a better finish with less tear-out/splintering, or if cross-cutting very narrow pieces.

Unless you are sawing large logs, the saw should be ok for a variety of uses.

Comment: hi RedGrittyBrick. I will be working with what's sold as studwork at varying levels of thickness (between an inch or two, perhaps bit thicker or less). Also sheets of wood if I can manage. What do you reckon in this case? I want to build small stuff to use around the house. Thanks again.

Comment: @Phil, for stuff that is visible inside the house you are likely to want a cleaner finish than you'll get with a general purpose handsaw. If I were you, I'd try the saw on your studwork 2x4s (or whatever) first. Then decide if you need a better saw for finer work. Sawing up large 2x4's with a fine-toothed saw would be much more work but could be done I suppose. I suggest researching rip-saws vs cross-cut saws etc. If I get time I'll expand this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much RedGrittyBrick, I will look into them all and read more.